# SQL Server concat Multiple values in XML string and return as single row

Tags: sql-server, xml

SQL Server 2012 Developer edition

**TESTMACHINE**:

```
OID MACHINENAME 
---------------
1    TEST A
2    TEST B
3    TEST C
```

**TESTDETAIL**:

```
OID TESTMACHINEOID TESTID   HISTORYID
-------------------------------------
1       1           200         100
2       1           300         250
3       2           1000        2345
4       3           100         150
```

`TestMachineOID` is the FK to the `TestMachine` table

I need to concatenate items into an XML by grouping `TestMachineOID`. Is it possible to get the below desired output?

```
TESTMACHINEOID  TESTMACHINENAME     TEXTXML
------------------------------------------------------------------------
1                   TEST A          <REC><TESTID>200</TESTID><HISTORYID>100<HISTORYID><TESTID>300</TESTID><HISTORYID>250<HISTORYID></REC>
2                   TEST B          <REC><TESTID>1000</TESTID><HISTORYID>2345<HISTORYID></REC>
3                   TEST C          <REC><TESTID>100</TESTID><HISTORYID>150<HISTORYID></REC>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
drop table #testmachine
drop table #testdetail

create table #testmachine (oid int , name nvarchar(10))
create table #testdetail (oid int, machineoid int, testid int, historyid int)

insert into #testmachine (oid, name) values (1,'A')
insert into #testmachine (oid, name) values (2,'B')
insert into #testmachine (oid, name) values (3,'C')

insert into #testdetail (oid, machineoid,testid,historyid) values (1,1,10,20)
insert into #testdetail (oid, machineoid,testid,historyid) values (2,1,30,40)
insert into #testdetail (oid, machineoid,testid,historyid) values (3,2,50,60)
insert into #testdetail (oid, machineoid,testid,historyid) values (4,2,70,80)
insert into #testdetail (oid, machineoid,testid,historyid) values (5,3,90,100)


select 
        tm.oid, 
        tm.name,
        (           
            select testid, historyid
            from #testdetail td 
            where td.machineoid = tm.oid
            for xml path('rec') , root('signal')
        ) as XMLvalue

from 
        #testmachine tm
```

output

```
1   A   <signal><rec><testid>10</testid><historyid>20</historyid></rec><rec><testid>30</testid><historyid>40</historyid></rec></signal>
2   B   <signal><rec><testid>50</testid><historyid>60</historyid></rec><rec><testid>70</testid><historyid>80</historyid></rec></signal>
3   C   <signal><rec><testid>90</testid><historyid>100</historyid></rec></signal>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a "for loop" and fill an additional table with it.

Loop through the testmachine table and for each OID select all records in testdetail, then with another nested for loop add them one by one with clause

SET TESTXML = CONCAT(TESTXML, new_value)